# Make Directory in python

Tags: python, ubuntu, mkdir

I want to make a directory in Python.

Here is my code:

```
dl_path = "~/Downloads/PDMB"

def main():
    if not os.path.exists(dl_path):
        print "path doesn't exist. trying to make"
        os.makedirs(dl_path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I want that pdmb be in Download folder in `$HOME` (by the way my OS is Ubuntu), but it makes Home/Downloads/pdmb in the same folder that my code is.

what should I do?

Comment: Ah ha, good dupe @user1767754

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to use expanduser to expand the '~' path

Here's the code you need

```
import os
from os.path import expanduser

home = expanduser('~')

dl_path = home + '/Downloads/PDMB'

def main():
    if not os.path.exists(dl_path):
       print "path doesn't exist. trying to make"
       os.makedirs(dl_path)



 if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: It would be simpler just to replace `dl_path = "~/Downloads/PDMB"`  in the original code with `dl_path = os.path.expanduser("~/Downloads/PDMB")` (or better yet,  `dl_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Downloads", "PDMB")`), since @ali-salehi is already  accessing `os.path`.